# JMeter - After Delete SQL, should I run a explicit commit

Tags: jmeter, sql-delete

I have this SQL that I'm running through the JMeter script using JDBC request.

Query Type: Update Statement

SQL:

delete from auth_table where auth_key < to_char(trunc(sysdate-${RetentionDays}),'YYYYMMDD') and rownum< ${NumberOfRecords}+1

Do I need to add another JDBC request only for commit?

Comment: Did you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with RetentionDays value being defined as 0. If it is a non-zero value it works

Answer (score 0):

Depends on Auto Commit flag in [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

> Turn auto commit on or off for the connections

Answer (score 0):

Normally JMeter shouldn't "hang" the main idea of the database load testing is that you should be sending exactly the same requests as your application (or other database data producer/consumer) does. You can look into your database logs and compare the requests which application and JMeter send, identify and eliminate the differences.

If you don't have access to the database server instance you can try the following JMeter-side troubleshootings:

1. Take a thread dump, it can be done either from JMeter GUI directly

   [image]

   or [using JDK built-in tools](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/TakeThreadDump.html), this way you will see where exactly JMeter "hangs"
2. Another option is [increasing JMeter logs verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for JDBC test elements, it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc" level="debug" />
   ```